# Undefined reference issue while creating executable

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to create executable using some libraries.
My GCC command is :-

```
gcc -fPIC -DLINUX testdenpli /verilog/libdenpli.so -L/local/test/dir/ testpli.c
```

I have my library with symbols at path '/local/test/dir/'

```
Error:-
libdenpli.so: undefined reference to `ktlTcl_InitStubs'
libdenpli.so: undefined reference to `ktlitclStubsPtr'
```

I have the libraries with above symbols at path "'/local/test/dir/" .. But still seeing the issue.

Any one please help.

Comment: Does Verilog have instructions on prerequisite libraries you need to install and what the correct compile/link configuration needs to be?

Comment: @lurker, Not getting you...Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: `libdenpli.so` requires linking another library that provides those undefined symbols. Check the documentation.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin , you mean it has some dependencies ? How to check what are the libraries that are dependent on 'libdenpli.so' library ?

Comment: This library must come with documentation explaining how to link against it.

Comment: I was asking if you read verilog's documentation regarding how to use their library.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that `libdenpli.so` requires linking another shared library that provides symbols `ktlTcl_InitStubs` and `ktlitclStubsPtr`.

Find the shared library that provides those symbols using the following command:

```
for so in $(find /local/test/dir -name "*.so" -o -name "*.so.*"); do
    nm --defined-only --dynamic $so 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'ktlTcl_InitStubs|ktlitclStubsPtr' && echo $so; 
done
```

Then add that library into your linker command line:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DLINUX -o testdenpli testpli.c /verilog/libdenpli.so <full-path-to-found-library>
```

Comment: I did not see any output from the above command. what is this --dynamic option for 'nm'? I can see the output if I run with just "nm  <expected_lib_with symbol> | grep ktlTcl_InitStubs " I am seeing output : - 0000000000038200 t ktlTcl_InitStubs ...

Comment: @jerry Check `man nm` for `--dynamic`. If you do not see any output, then those symbols can be in a `.a`.

Comment: Seems like that is the issue.. The library 'libdenpli.so' has the symbol 'ktlTcl_InitStubs ' with 't' . will it only work if the symbol is with 'D' dynamic?

Comment: @jerry Symbol `ktlTcl_InitStubs` is not defined in `libdenpli.so`, that is what the error message says. Do `nm --defined-only libdenpli.so`.

Comment: Yes, when I try to do this "nm --defined-only libdenpli.so | grep ktlTcl_InitStubs " I did not see any output. seems like it is undefined. Maxim, How can I fix this issue. Please help

Comment: @jerry As I mentioned, you need to find a library that implements those symbols. May be you need to implement these functions yourself. I would read the documentation to find out.

Comment: okay, you mean to say that I need to get the library with that symbol defined "D" . Can you share the documentation if any ?

Answer (score -1):

What is the name of the library containing the symbols? You need to include -lNAME to your compilation.
In general,

`gcc file.c -o file -L/path/to/libs -lNAME`

Note, the prefix "lib" and the suffix ".so" needn't be mentioned.

Comment: Nope, the author does it right. With your command line it will link but won't run.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Why won't it run once the symbols are resolved? I'm just pointing out that the name of the library is missing in the compilation.

Comment: It won't run because runtime linker `ld.so` won't find it in a non-standard location. That requires `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/libs` command line option. If you just link against `/verilog/libdenpli.so` that doesn't require `-L` and `-Wl,-rpath=...`.